# Regex - capture character before pattern until a specific character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match `h.Z.getAssetUrl("/FullLogo.svg")` from the following string

```
4H18V5.2H2z"})),t)})),p=t(7103),h=t(1313),m=function(){return(0,o.jsx)(a.Ee,{src:`h.Z.getAssetUrl("/FullLogo.svg")`,width:"195px",height:"36px"})},g=function(e){var r=e.toggle,t=e.isOpen;return(0,o.jsx)(i.xu,{display:{base:"block",md:"none"}
```

I've tried `/getAssetUrl\(.+?\)/`, this matches `getAssetUrl("/FullLogo.svg")`. How do I also match the `h.Z.` before it. I want to match ahead until a `:` is encounterd.

Comment: So match all but `:`, ``/[^:]*getAssetUrl\([^()]*\)/``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following regex. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/1qnMaH/1) for following regex.

```
^.*?:\K(?:.*?\.){2}(?:.*?"){2}\)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^.*?:         ##From starting of value matching till very first occurrence of : using lazy match here.
\K            ##Forget previous match by \K option till here so that we can print only required output.
(?:           ##Opening a non-capturing group here.
  .*?\.       ##Matching till dot by doing a lazy match here.
){2}          ##Match 2 occurrence of lazy matches(means match till 2 dots only).
(?:.*?"){2}\) ##In a non-capturing group matching till " as a lazy match and by mentioning {2} means perform two matches of it followed by a \ to get needed value.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match all but `:` chars before your pattern:

```
/[^:]*getAssetUrl\([^()]*\)/
```

I also suggest using a negated character class to match a string between two parentheses.

*Details*:

- `[^:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`
- `getAssetUrl\(` - a `getAssetUrl(` string
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` chars
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xPtMcL/1).